# input type hidden from javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Happy New Years.  I have a simple javascript math equation and I'm able to display the results fairly easy using HTML but I'd also like the results in a hidden Input field so that when the form gets submitted via email the variable is part of the email as well.

Here is my javascript code:

```
function updateScore(ele,val){
    var score = document.getElementById('score');
    var riskLevel = document.getElementById('risklevel');

    var curScore = parseFloat(score.innerHTML);
    curScore += (ele.checked ? val : -val);
    score.innerHTML = curScore;

    if(curScore <= 1){
        riskLevel.innerHTML = "Low";
        $("#scan_icon").html('<img src="img/RiskLow.jpg">');
    }else if(curScore <= 2){
        riskLevel.innerHTML = "Moderate";
        $("#scan_icon").html('<img src="img/RiskModerate.jpg">');
    }else if(curScore <= 4){
        riskLevel.innerHTML = "High";
        $("#scan_icon").html('<img src="img/RiskHigh.jpg">');
    }else{
        riskLevel.innerHTML = "Very High";
        $("#scan_icon").html('<img src="img/RiskVeryHigh.jpg">');
    }
}
```

How would I display 'score' in a hidden input?  Tried several things but couldn't get it to work.  This isn't working:

```
<input name="Risk Score: " input id="score" value="" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: set the `value` property of the element.

Comment: you should use `score.value = curScore;`

Comment: Which several thing did u tryd plz share

Comment: actually u r already using score as id in somewhere so I have updated my answer u need to change id of hidden input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store score in hidden input using jQuery as like that:

```
 $("#scorehidden").val(curScore);
```

And one more thing your HTML for hidden input should be like this:

```
<input name="RiskScore"  id="scorehidden" value="" type="hidden" />
```

Side note: you are already using score as a id in any div etc... so I changed the id name as scorehidden.

Comment: Sorry still not working using method above by devpro.  On the form the risk score is coming up empty.

Comment: @jeff-s actually u r already use score as id in somewhere so I have updated my answer u need to change id of hidden input

Comment: Thanks devpro, revision worked!

Comment: You are welxome @jeff-s now mark as accepted the best answer this will help for others by click on left green tick

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to ad something akin to

```
document.getElementById('score').value = curScore;
```

Using jQuery, you would do it this way:

```
$('#score').val(curScore);
```

Comment: Yes store value in simple java script like that.

Comment: Brother change id name he is already this id in any div. This will not work chk my answer